# Minetest: Revoking and granting player privileges

Tags: lua, minetest

I want to revoke the `interact` privilege from a player (let's call him `singleplayer`). I tried

```lua
minetest.set_player_privs("singleplayer", {interact = false})
```

But this revokes *all other privileges*, and *grants* `interact`. I then tried

```lua
local privs = minetest.get_player_privs("singleplayer")
privs.interact = false
minetest.set_player_privs("singleplayer", privs)
```

But this does not revoke `interact`; it even *grants* `interact` if the player doesn't already have it.

For granting the `interact` privilege, I tried `minetest.set_player_privs("singleplayer", {interact = true})`. This worked, but revoked all other privileges.

Answer (score 3):

This is a well-known Minetest "footgun". The table passed to `set_player_privs` is treated as a *set* of privileges. Unlike `ObjRef:set_properties`, `set_player_privs` is not "incremental": It does not "modify" the player privileges, it *replaces* ("sets") them.

Let's look at the first example:

```lua
minetest.set_player_privs("singleplayer", {interact = false})
```

Minetest treats the table as a *set*: It only looks at the keys. The only key is `interact`, so it sets the privileges of singleplayer to a *just `interact`*.

Similarly, in

```lua
local privs = minetest.get_player_privs("singleplayer")
privs.interact = false
minetest.set_player_privs("singleplayer", privs)
```

`interact` is still a table key; it *does not matter* that its value is `false` (or `"foobar"`, or `42.101`...) - Minetest only looks at the keys, never at the values. So the new set will contain all previous privileges as keys, as well as `interact`. This will grant `interact` if the player doesn't already have it.

To revoke `interact`, you need to remove it from the table by setting it to `nil`:

```lua
local privs = minetest.get_player_privs("singleplayer")
privs.interact = nil
minetest.set_player_privs("singleplayer", privs)
```

Similarly, to grant `interact`, you just add it to the table by setting it to a non-`nil` value (ideally `true`):

```lua
local privs = minetest.get_player_privs("singleplayer")
privs.interact = true
minetest.set_player_privs("singleplayer", privs)
```